# Jqueryui image reference no error but image not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

What am I missing here?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, downloaded the JqueryUI combined via Nuget package.

As image below, there's no error reference for file css/js but the close button is not showing.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

**EDIT**

I have also included the path for bundle.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you load the `css` files in your website? Bear in mind that adding the files using Nuget does not modify things like bundles, it just add the files and references to your project.

Comment: Yes. I have added it. Edited my question, also attached images for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have bootstrap also included into your project. It got conflict with jQuery-UI.

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.fn.button.noConflict) {
        $.fn.btn = $.fn.button.noConflict();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! You just solved my problem. Thank you so much. Will this also not conflict with any of the bootstrap css?

Comment: you can prevent conflict if you pass `$` to anonymous function like this: `(function($){ // code })(jQuery)`. 
By wrapping any jQuery using code in that construct you redefine $ to jQuery for the contained part without coming into conflict with other code in the page.